# PGF Keys - how to reuse code

Tags: macros, pgfkeys

I like to define a custom figure command with multiple sub-labels and references in the caption:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=100pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfkeys{/myfigure/.is family, /myfigure,
label a/.initial=a,
label a/.store in =\labelA,
label b/.initial=b,
label b/.store in =\labelB,
caption a/.initial={},
caption b/.initial={},
}

\pgfkeys{myfigure,#1}
\newcommand\myfigure[1]{
\begin{figure}
    {\phantomsubcaption\label{\labelA}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{\labelB}}
    \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image-a}
    \caption{
        (\subref{\labelA}) \pgfkeysvalueof{/myfigure/caption a} 
        (\subref{\labelB}) \pgfkeysvalueof{/myfigure/caption b} 
    }
\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\myfigure{
    label a = figa,
    caption a = caption 1,
    label b = figb,
    caption  b = caption 2,
}

\end{document}
```

The result should look like

[image]

Is it possible to define `\myfigure{...}` such that don't need to define a variable for each sub-label/sub-caption? E.g.:

```
\myfigure{
    label = figa,
    caption = caption 1,
    label = figb
    caption = caption 2,
}
```

Here is a failed attempt of my idea:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=100pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgf}

\pgfkeys{/myfigure/.is family, /myfigure,
sublabels/.initial = {},
fullcaption/.initial = {},
label/.initial=a,
label/.store in=\mylabel,
label/.style={sublabels/.append={\phantomsubcaption\label{subfig:#1}}},
caption/.initial={},
caption/.style={fullcaption/.append={(\subref{subfig:\mylabel}) #1}},
}

\newcommand\myfigure[1]{
\pgfkeys{/myfigure,#1}
\begin{figure}
    \pgfkeys{/myfigure, sublabels}
    \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image-a}
    \pgfkeys{/myfigure, fullcaption}
\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\myfigure{
    label = figa,
    caption = caption 1,
    label = figb,
    caption = caption 2,
}

\ref{subfig:figa}

\end{document}
```

Here, I just get the error message

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   sub@subfig:\mylabel

[image]

Somehow `\mylabel` does not get expanded inside `fullcaption/.style`

Comment: Why exactly are you loading `subcaption`? You don't seem to be using it.

Comment: @cfr I am using the `\phantomsubcaption` and `\subref` command.

Comment: I guess what I really mean is, why not just use sub-captions if these are sub-0captions? Why roll your own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea is to store the label/caption pairs as `\mysubcap{label}{caption}` in a macro `\mysubcaps`. After processing the pgfkeys in your example, `\mysubcaps` will contain

```
\mysubcap{figa}{caption 1}\mysubcap{figb}{caption 2}
```

Now you can process these pairs by `\let`ting `\mysubcap` to a command with two arguments and then executing `\mysubcaps`. By `\let`ing `\mysubcap` to different commands, you can process the pairs in different ways.

To be able to specify the pairs in the form

```
\myfigure{subcaption={figa}{caption 1},subcaption={figb}{caption 2}}
```

we set up the pgf key `subcaption` as

```
\pgfkeys
  {/myfigure/subcaption/.code 2 args=
    {\expandafter\def\expandafter\mysubcaps\expandafter
       {\mysubcaps\mysubcap{#1}{#2}%
       }%
    }%
  }
```

To process the options, we have to clear the macro `\mysubcaps` and then call `\pgfkeys` with the options.

```
\def\mysubcaps{}%
\pgfkeys{/myfigure/.cd,subcaption={figa}{caption 1},subcaption={figb}{caption 2}}%
```

Below is the complete code that integrates the fragments into the definition of your command `\myfigure`. One caveat: Using fancy macros in a `\caption` command may result in all kinds of strange errors, since `\caption` writes its argument in expanded form to the `aux` file. At least for the testing phase I recommend to use `\caption[]{...}` instead of `\caption{...}`; then the empty optional argument is written to the `aux` file.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys
  {/myfigure/subcaption/.code 2 args=
    {\expandafter\def\expandafter\mysubcaps\expandafter
       {\mysubcaps\mysubcap{#1}{#2}%
       }%
    }%
  }
\newcommand\mysubcap{}% make sure \mysubcap is not in use
\newcommand\mysubcaps{}% make sure \mysubcaps is not in use
\newcommand\mysubcapphantom[2]{{\phantomsubcaption\label{#1}}}
\newcommand\mysubcapsubref[2]{ (\subref{#1}) #2}
\newcommand\myfigure[1]%
  {\def\mysubcaps{}% clear \mysubcaps
   \pgfkeys{/myfigure/.cd,#1}% store subcaption={X}{Y} as \mysubcap{X}{Y} in \mysubcaps
   \begin{figure}
   \centering
   \let\mysubcap\mysubcapphantom
   \mysubcaps
   \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image-a}%
   \let\mysubcap\mysubcapsubref
   \caption{\mysubcaps}%
   \end{figure}
  }
\begin{document}
\myfigure
  {subcaption={figa}{caption 1},
   subcaption={figb}{caption 2}
  }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @gernot! I will take a look into this `\expandafter` socery.

Comment: @grbl There is no sorcery involved. Basically we do `\def\list{\list\newitem}` to append the new item to the list. For this to work we have to expand the `\list` in the body of the macro before redefining `\list`. This is done by inserting an `\expandafter` between any two tokens up to the `\list` that should be expanded first.